# Error when trying to append a button to a li item JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to create a to-do list with HTML, CSS, Javascript.
I want to have the following functionality:

1. An input box where the user can type the item.
2. 2 buttons: Enter and Clear
3. On the press of the key "Enter" the item gets added to the list
4. On the press of the button "Enter" the item gets added to the list
5. On the press of  the button "Clear" all items are removed from the list
6. 6.1When pressing on a specific item, it gets crossed off (Done)
   6.2. When an item is pressed, a button shows up, with the text "Remove" so you can remove only that item from the list.

I've managed to do 1 to 6.1, but have not been able to work out how to would do the 6.2 yet.
Code of what I've been trying below.

Javascript:
line 8 - creating the Remove button
lines 70 - 82 - function to append the button and listener for click.

I got the following error: script.js:79 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

```js
// Store elements in variables 

var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var clear = document.getElementById("clear");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
var delBtn = document.createElement("button").innerHTML = "Remove";




//CREATING NEW ITEM IN LIST
// Check if the input is not empty

function inputLength() {
  return input.value.length;
}

//Create new item and restore input to default
function createListElement() {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
  ul.appendChild(li);
  input.value = "";

}

// ADDING ITEMS AFTER CLICK

// Add item after click function

function addListAfterClick() {
  if (inputLength() > 0) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

//Add item after click listner 
button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);


//ADDING ITEMS AFTER ENTER

// Add item after Enter Function
function addListAfterKeypress(event) {
  if (inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13) {
    createListElement();
  }
}

//Add item after enter Listener 
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterKeypress);


//MARKING AS DONE (line-thorugh)
//Mark as done function

function markAsDone(evt) {
  if (evt.target.tagName === "LI") {
    evt.target.classList.toggle("Done");
  }
}


//Mark as done listener
ul.addEventListener("click", markAsDone);


//DELETE BUTTON WHEN DONE
// Add Delete Button when class name is Done

function addRemove() {
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    if (li[1].className === "Done") {
      li[i].appendChild(delBtn)
    }
  }
}

//Add listener for delBtn
ul.addEventListener("click", addRemove);

//CLEARING ENTIRE LIST

//Clear Entire list function
function clearList() {
  ul.innerHTML = "";
}

//Clear entire list listner
clear.addEventListener("click", clearList);
```

```css
html {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ca/68/73/ca6873339d2734623797a3e03e20b06f.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.upbar {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.Done {
  text-decoration: line-through #ff3c3c;
}

li {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

button.red {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #D14836);
  border: 1px solid #DD4B39;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #C04131;
}

button.red:hover {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #C53727);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #C53727);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #DD4B39, #C53727);
  border: 1px solid #AF301F;
}

button.red:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D74736, #AD2719);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D74736, #AD2719);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #D74736, #AD2719);
}

button.blue {
  color: white;
  background: #4C8FFB;
  border: 1px #3079ED solid;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #80B0FB;
}

button.blue:hover {
  border: 1px #2F5BB7 solid;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #EAEAEA, inset 0 1px 0 #5A94F1;
  background: #3F83F1;
}

button.blue:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 5px #2370FE;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>My to do list</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class=wrapper>
    <header>
      <h1>To Do List</h1>
      <p id="first">Get it done today</p>
    </header>
    <div class="upbar">
      <input id="userinput" type="text" placeholder="Enter items">
      <button class="blue" id="enter">Enter</button>
      <button class="red" id="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <div class="List">
      <ul>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

<h
```

Comment: 1. `var delBtn = document.createElement("button").innerHTML = "Remove";` will record the string `"Remove"` as `delBtn`, not the button itself. The return value of the assignment is the right-hand side of the assignment. 2. The loop that adds `delBtn` wouldn't work even if 1. was fixed - an element can exist on only one place in the DOM. Assigning *the same* DOM node to a new parent will *move* the node, not clone it.

Comment: Also have ONE click event listener - right now, clicking anything un the UL will clear the list

Comment: @VLAZ: Thank you, that makes sense. I changed it to first create a bigger div, to which I attach both the LI item and the delete button, complete button (also change the way  I created those, no longer at the beginning, but in in function itself ).

Comment: @mplungjan: working on the listeners now, should work since I have different elements to listen to, thank you!